# Read file until certain line in Clojure using doseq

Tags: clojure

This would normally be trivial in other language, but I've found no such example in Clojure.

I can println an entire file using:

```
(with-open [rdr (io/reader "file")]
          (doseq [line (line-seq rdr) :while (< count(line) 10)]
            (println line)))
```

But how do I get it to stop at line 5?

Thanks.

Comment: You should move that bracket before `line` one symbol to the left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(println
 (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "file")]
   (let [ls (line-seq rdr)]
     (doall (take 5 ls)))))
```

This will print first 5 lines of the specified file.

If you need skip some lines that does not satisfy the condition, you can add `filter`. The following code will print first five lines that the length is less than 10.

```
(println
 (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "file")]
   (let [ls (line-seq rdr)]
     (->> ls
          (filter #(< (count %) 10))
          (take 5)
          (doall)))))
```

Since `filter` and `take` returns lazy sequence, it should be realized within the `with-open` form. Outside the `with-open` form, the sequence couldn't be realized and cause exception.

`println` function also make the sequence realized, you can modify the code like this:

```
(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "data/base_exp.txt")]
  (let [ls (line-seq rdr)]
    (->> ls
         (filter #(> (count %) 10))
         (take 5)
         (println))))
```

Comment: It might help future readers to explain why `doall` is necessary.

Comment: The second example does not stop reading at line 5. Instead, it stops reading at the fifth line with less than 10 characters.

Comment: `doall` is needed because `take` returns a lazy sequence

Comment: Some part of description were not as clear as I expected. I updated the post.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use [`take`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/take) to limit the amount of lines:

Replace

```
   (doseq [line (line-seq rdr) ;; ...
```

with

```
   (doseq [line (take 5 (line-seq rdr)) ;; ...
```